# Reading JSON object in Apex

Tags: apex, rest-api, json

I have the following code and i need help to read geographic object value from the JSON string. Can any one help me out how to read geographic object.

```
Http http = new Http();
HttpRequest request = new HttpRequest();
HttpResponse response = new HttpResponse();
String urlAdd = 'https://geocoding.geo.census.gov/geocoder/geographies/address?street=3912+Bel+Pre+Rd&city=Silver+Spring&state=MD&zip=20906&benchmark=4&vintage=4&layers=54&format=json';
request.setEndpoint(urlAdd);
request.setMethod('GET');
response = http.send(request);
String jString = response.getBody();
System.debug('** jString *** '+jString);
jString = jString.replace('115th Congressional Districts', 'CongressionalDistricts');
System.debug('### jString ## '+jString);
Map<String,Object> resultJSON2Apex = (Map<String,Object>) JSON.deserializeUntyped(jString);
Map<String,Object> step1 = (Map<String,Object>) resultJSON2Apex.get('result');
System.debug('### step1 ## '+step1);
String strstep1 = JSON.serializePretty(step1);
Map<String,Object> strstep1deSeri = (Map<String,Object>) JSON.deserializeUntyped(strstep1);
List<Object> strstep1deSeriAddrMatch = (List<Object>) strstep1deSeri.get('addressMatches');
System.debug('# strstep1deSeriAddrMatch #' +strstep1deSeriAddrMatch);
```

Sample JSON return

```
{
  "result": {
    "input": {
      "address": {
        "state": "MD",
        "street": "3912 Bel Pre Rd",
        "zip": "20906",
        "city": "Silver Spring"
      },
      "benchmark": {
        "id": "4",
        "isDefault": false,
        "benchmarkName": "Public_AR_Current",
        "benchmarkDescription": "Public Address Ranges - Current Benchmark"
      },
      "vintage": {
        "id": "4",
        "isDefault": true,
        "vintageName": "Current_Current",
        "vintageDescription": "Current Vintage - Current Benchmark"
      }
    },
    "addressMatches": [
      {
        "geographies": {
          "115th Congressional Districts": [
            {
              "OID": 211904690760711,
              "STATE": "24",
              "FUNCSTAT": "N",
              "NAME": "Congressional District 8",
              "AREAWATER": 24118929,
              "CDSESSN": "115",
              "LSADC": "C2",
              "CENTLON": "-077.2510770",
              "BASENAME": "8",
              "INTPTLAT": "+39.4222969",
              "MTFCC": "G5200",
              "GEOID": "2408",
              "CENTLAT": "+39.4329513",
              "CD115": "08",
              "INTPTLON": "-077.2420034",
              "AREALAND": 2226201063
            }
          ]
        },
        "matchedAddress": "3912 BEL PRE RD, SILVER SPRING, MD, 20906",
        "coordinates": {
          "x": -77.076225,
          "y": 39.093773
        },
        "tigerLine": {
          "tigerLineId": "62060191",
          "side": "L"
        },
        "addressComponents": {
          "suffixDirection": "",
          "suffixQualifier": "",
          "fromAddress": "3902",
          "preQualifier": "",
          "preDirection": "",
          "preType": "",
          "streetName": "BEL PRE",
          "suffixType": "RD",
          "toAddress": "3912",
          "state": "MD",
          "zip": "20906",
          "city": "SILVER SPRING"
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: You should **[edit]** your post to include some sample JSON...

Comment: ... because if the JSON is appropriate, https://json2apex.herokuapp.com/ is a great way of reading JSON data and having automatically generated classes to hold the data.

Comment: Pity about the "115th Congressional Districts" in the JSON: valid JSON but not valid as a class or field name in the JSON2Apex. Looks like it may be possible to manually modify the JSON2Apex "Create explicit parse code" output though.

Comment: @KeithC : I need the following values in a List or any temp variable so that i can update those values in an object. I need help in reading this values. "OID": 211904690760711,
              "STATE": "24",
              "FUNCSTAT": "N",
              "NAME": "Congressional District 8",
              "AREAWATER": 24118929,
              "CDSESSN": "115",
              "LSADC": "C2",
              "CENTLON": "-077.2510770",
              "BASENAME": "8",
              "INTPTLAT": "+39.4222969",
              "MTFCC": "G5200",
              "GEOID": "2408"

Comment: In my code I am replacing the string.  jString = jString.replace('115th Congressional Districts', 'CongressionalDistricts');

Comment: I would do it the way you are doing it using a series of `JSON.deserializeUntyped`. Using that approach there is no need to replace the awkward string as its value will end up as a map key of type string that can have spaces etc in it. Suggest you persevere... you are probably nearly there.